# Simple WHERE EXISTS ... ORDER BY... query very slow in PostrgeSQL

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, sql-execution-plan, postgres-9.6, partial-index

I have this very simple query, generated by my ORM (Entity Framework Core):

```
SELECT *
 FROM "table1" AS "t1"
 WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM "table2" AS "t2"
     WHERE ("t2"."is_active" = TRUE) AND ("t1"."table2_id" = "t2"."id"))
 ORDER BY "t1"."table2_id"
```

1. There are 2 "is_active" records. The other involved columns ("id") are the primary keys. Query returns exactly 4 rows.
2. Table 1 is 96 million records.
3. Table 2 is 30 million records.
4. The 3 columns involved in this query are indexed (is_active, id, table2_id).
5. The C#/LINQ code that generates this simple query is: Table2.Where(t => t.IsActive).Include(t => t.Table1).ToList();`
6. `SET STATISTICS 10000` was set to all of the 3 columns.
7. `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` was run on both tables.

WITHOUT the `ORDER BY` clause, the query returns within a few milliseconds, and I’d expect nothing else for 4 records to return. EXPLAIN output:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=1.13..13.42 rows=103961024 width=121)
  ->  Index Scan using table2_is_active_idx on table2  (cost=0.56..4.58 rows=1 width=8)
        Index Cond: (is_active = true)
        Filter: is_active
  ->  Index Scan using table1_table2_id_fkey on table1 t1 (cost=0.57..8.74 rows=10 width=121)
        Index Cond: (table2_id = table1.id)
```

WITH the `ORDER BY` clause, the query takes 5 minutes to complete! EXPLAIN output:

```
Merge Semi Join  (cost=10.95..4822984.67 rows=103961040 width=121)
  Merge Cond: (t1.table2_id = t2.id)
  ->  Index Scan using table1_table2_id_fkey on table1 t1  (cost=0.57..4563070.61 rows=103961040 width=121)
  ->  Sort  (cost=4.59..4.59 rows=2 width=8)
        Sort Key: t2.id
        ->  Index Scan using table2_is_active_idx on table2 a  (cost=0.56..4.58 rows=2 width=8)
              Index Cond: (is_active = true)
              Filter: is_active
```

The inner, first index scan should return no more than 2 rows. Then the outer, second index scan doesn't make any sense with its cost of 4563070 and 103961040 rows. It only has to match 2 rows in `table2` with 4 rows in `table1`!

This is a very simple query with very few records to return. Why is Postgres failing to execute it properly?

Comment: You need to include both of the explain plans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I solved my problem in the most unexpected way. I upgraded Postgresql from 9.6.1 to 9.6.3. And that was it. After restarting the service, the explain plan now looked good and the query ran just fine this time. I did not change anything, no new index, nothing. The only explanation I can think of is that there is was a query planner bug in 9.6.1 and solved in 9.6.3. Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: There is no bug most probably. Query planner is very complicated and it doesn't always make the correct decisions. It's not guaranteed your query will continue to run fine in a few weeks or after another upgrade.

Comment: @JakubKania: True in general. But it just so happens that there was a bug in 9.6.1 that fits the case. And for value frequencies that clear, Postgres will *never* make such a wrong decision again after the bug fix and once the partial index is in place.

Answer (score 3):

Add an index:

```
CREATE INDEX _index 
ON table2 
USING btree (id) 
WHERE is_active IS TRUE;
```

And rewrite query like this

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON (table1.table2_id = table2.id)
WHERE table2.is_active IS TRUE 
ORDER BY table2.id
```

It is necessary to take into account that "is_active IS TRUE" and "is_active = TRUE" process by PostgreSQL in different ways. So the expression in the index predicate and the query must match.

If u can't rewrite query try add an index:

```
CREATE INDEX _index 
ON table2 
USING btree (id) 
WHERE is_active = TRUE;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is a good idea and I didn't know we could do partial indexes like that. My problem was solved by upgrading Postgres to the latest minor version, that's the last thing that I thought would fix it.

Comment: Interesting, can you update post with new explain plan?

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is right, there ***is a bug in Postgres 9.6.1*** that fits your use case exactly. And upgrading was the right thing to do. [Upgrading to the latest point-release is ***always*** the right thing to do.](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

[Quoting the release notes for Postgres 9.6.2:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-9-6-2.html)

> - Fix foreign-key-based join selectivity estimation for semi-joins and
>     anti-joins, as well as inheritance cases (Tom Lane)
>
>   The new code for taking the existence of a foreign key relationship
>     into account did the wrong thing in these cases, making the estimates
>     worse not better than the pre-9.6 code.

You should still create that partial index like [Dima advised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45267361/939860). But keep it simple:

`is_active = TRUE` and `is_active IS TRUE` [subtly differ](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html) in that the second returns `FALSE` instead of `NULL` for `NULL` input. But none of this matters in a *`WHERE`* clause where only `TRUE` qualifies. And both expressions are just noise. In Postgres you can use **`boolean`** values directly:

```
CREATE INDEX t2_id_idx ON table2 (id) WHERE is_active;  -- that's all
```

And do ***not*** rewrite your query with a `LEFT JOIN`. This would add rows consisting of NULL values to the result for "active" rows in `table2` without any siblings in `table1`. To match your current logic it would have to be an `[INNER] JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM   table2 t2
JOIN   table1 t1 ON t1.table2_id = t2.id  -- and no parentheses needed
WHERE  t2.is_active  -- that's all
ORDER  BY t1.table2_id;
```

But there is no need to rewrite your query that way at all. The `EXISTS` semi-join you have is just as good. Results in the same query plan once you have the partial index.

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM table2
   WHERE  is_active  -- that's all
   WHERE  id = t1.table2_id
   )
ORDER  BY table2_id;
```

BTW, since you fixed the bug by upgrading and once you have created that partial index (and run `ANALYZE` or `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the table at least once - or autovacuum did that for you), you will ***never*** again get a bad query plan for this, since Postgres maintains separate estimates for the partial index, which are unambiguous for your numbers. Details:

- [Get count estimates from pg_class.reltuples for given conditions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115873/get-count-estimates-from-pg-class-reltuples-for-given-conditions/115918#115918)
- [Index that is not used, yet influences query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72649/index-that-is-not-used-yet-influences-query)